# OnIdiom for Grid columnspan

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, columnspan, detection-idiom

I need to use OnIdiom for grid column definition, but it isn't working. See my code below. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and suggest a solution?

```
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                            <OnIdiom  x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="64.9*" Phone="99.8*"/>
                        </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                            <OnIdiom  x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="0.1*" Phone="0.1*"/>
                        </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                    </ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition.Width>
                            <OnIdiom  x:TypeArguments="GridLength" Tablet="35*" Phone="0.1*"/>
                        </ColumnDefinition.Width>
                    </ColumnDefinition>
```

This does not help, so I did:

```
<Grid.ColumnSpan>
       <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" Phone="3" Tablet="1"/>
</Grid.ColumnSpan>
```

This also not helps.

Comment: Could you explain what is not working? Is the code not compiling? Or are the results in the UI not as expected?

Comment: nevermind. fixed that. Thanks

Comment: Could you post your solution as an answer, so that others know what you did to fix it?

Comment: yeah , sure....

Answer (score 2):

x:DataType instead of x:TypeArguments works for me..

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition >
        <RowDefinition.Height>
            <OnIdiom x:DataType="GridLength" Tablet=".25*" Phone="0.075*" />
        </RowDefinition.Height>
    </RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition >
        <RowDefinition.Height>
            <OnIdiom x:DataType="GridLength" Tablet="*" Phone="0.85*" />
        </RowDefinition.Height>
    </RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition >
        <RowDefinition.Height>
            <OnIdiom x:DataType="GridLength" Tablet=".25*" Phone="0.075*" />
        </RowDefinition.Height>
    </RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: this is Accepted answer @Riyas

Answer (score 0):

```
override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
     //according with height and width you can design your layouts
     if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Phone)
     {
       // layout views vertically
     } 
     else
     {
       // layout views horizontally or use different Page
     }
}
```